# First value of a Singly-Linked List deleted on a swap attempt with another value (C++ code)

Tags: singly-linked-list

I've been working in this program that takes two integers and swap their positions on a Singly-Linked List. It works well for all the values in the list but when I try to swap any value with the very first in the list, all the values in between them get erased instead of swapping and I can't see where the problem is coming from. Here is the swapping code I wrote:

void singlyLLSwapNodes(SLLNode* head, int x, int y){

```
if (head != nullptr && head->next != nullptr)
{
    SLLNode* prevNode1 = NULL, * prevNode2 = NULL, * node1 = head, * node2 = head, * temp = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    if (x == y)
        return;

    //search for x
    while (node1 != NULL && node1->data != x)
    {
        prevNode1 = node1;
        node1 = node1->next;
    }

    // search for y
    while (node2 != NULL && node2->data != y)
    {
        prevNode2 = node2;
        node2 = node2->next;
    }

    if (node1 != NULL && node2 != NULL)
    {
        if (prevNode1 != NULL)
            prevNode1->next = node2;
        else
            head = node2;

        if (prevNode2 != NULL)
            prevNode2->next = node1;
        else
            head = node1;

        //swaps the next nodes of node1 and node 2
        temp = node1->next;
        node1->next = node2->next;
        node2->next = temp;

    }
    else {

        cout << "swapping nodes is not possible!\n";
    }
}// end of if statement
```

}// end of swapping function

I also made a video explaining the situation and showing what happens, if you can take a look at:

https://www.eddiedemeira.com/stackoverflow.html